# C#. datagridviewcomboboxcolumn - список выпадает не с первого нажатия

Tags: c#, datagridview

В dataGridView есть столбцы datagridviewcomboboxcolumn. Почему на такую ячейку нужно нажать несколько раз, прежде чем выпадет список? Как-то можно сделать, чтобы с первого нажатия выпадал список?

Comment: При клике на ячейку вызывать выпадание списка в ручную. Пример - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241100/how-to-manually-drop-down-a-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Comment: @DenisE, спасибо за информацию